# passing data from AuthenticationProvider to success url spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a springboot application which uses spring security for authentication. Once authenticated, I would like send some data to the `successForwardUrl` or `defaultSuccessUrl` mapping. e.g.

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  ...
  .successForwardUrl("/home")
  .defaultSuccessUrl("/home",true)
  ...
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {   
    auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {
     @Override
     public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
      UserDO userDO = service.authenticate(auth.getName(),auth.getCredentials().toString());
      if(userDO != null{ //<-- get this DO to /home
       return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                                (name, password, Collections.emptyList());
      }else{
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

As shown above, I want to get `UserDO` in the `/home` mapping. Any idea?